# How to get spaCy to use universal dependencies

Tags: nlp, spacy, dependency-parsing

Spacy's site said they use universal dependencies scheme in their annotations specifications page. But when I parse "I love you", '''you''' was made a "dobj" of "love". There's no "dobj" in the universal dependency relations doc. So I have two questions :

1. How to get spacy to use the universal dependency relations?
2. How to get the doc for the relations spacy uses?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacy's provided models don't use UD dependencies for English or German. From the docs, where you can find tables for the dependency labels (https://spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing):

> The individual labels are language-specific and depend on the training corpus.

For most other models / languages, UD dependencies are used.

Comment: Are there examples showing how an individual dependency is linked, like the way UD explains their dependencies?

Comment: Here is the technical report about the ClearNLP dependency conversion for English: https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~choi/doc/cu-2012-choi.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> How to get spacy to use the universal dependency relations?

According to the spaCy official documentation, all spaCy models are trained using the Universal Dependency Corpora which is language-specific. According to English, you can see the full list of labels from this [link](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing-english) where you can find `dojb` listed as `direct object`.

> How to get the doc for the relations spacy uses?

I don't know what you mean by **doc**. If you mean documentation, I already provided the official documentation when answering the first question. Also, you can use `spacy.explain()` to get faster results like so:

```
>>> import spacy
>>>
>>> spacy.explain('dobj')
direct object
>>>
>>> spcay.explain('nsubj')
nominal subject
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: I found this on ClearNLP too. I was hoping to get some examples like what UD provides. Sometimes I don't know what they mean in even if they have the explain.